# write a code to replace 'the' with 'a' or 'an' using the vowels grammar

Tags: python, replace, conditional-statements

using simple python (no library using) to create function get string and then return that string with replace the with a or an using the grammar condition
i have written this code but whatever i write in the if condition it skips it and go to else

```
def replaceThe(txt: str) -> str:
    vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
    word=('a-z')
    if txt== :
        return(txt.replace('the', 'a'))
    else:
        return(txt.replace('the', 'an'))
```

well i left the txt condition empty cause i don't know what to write

Comment: what is text, is it just one word ? single line ? a paragraph ?

Comment: Python's str.replace() replaces ALL instances of a substring. Consider the case of `the owl and the dog`. We want to turn this into `an owl and a dog`, so we can't simply use one or the other. `str.split(' ')` might be a useful function for you--it turns a string into a list, separated by the argument (in this case, spaces). So you'd get the list `['the', 'owl', 'and', 'the', 'dog']`. Can you do anything with that?

Comment: stackoverflow is not here to do your homework for you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a naive implementation using the text splitted as words:

```
def replaceThe(txt: str) -> str:
    vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}
    words = txt.split()
    for i, w in enumerate(words):
        if w == 'the' and i<len(words)-1:
            words[i] = 'an' if words[i+1][0] in vowels else 'a'
    return ' '.join(words)

replaceThe('this is the test of the algorithm')
# 'this is a test of an algorithm'
```

*NB. I kept the logic minimal, it doesn't handle case, punctuation, etc. I leave it to you to implement it!*